# FullCalendar Add button to TH fc-day

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add a image for a dropdown (or hover) menu in the header with daynames in FullCalendar weekview. Something like this  http://img29.imageshack.us/img29/7440/nbf.png

This is the place I'm trying to append a DIV but so far with no luck.

```
<th class="fc-day-header fc-tue fc-widget-header" style="width: 233px;">Tir 6/8</th>
```

So far I tried to append a div with just some text, to see where it ended up:

```
$(".fc-mon").prepend("<div style='position:relative;top:0px;left:0px'>[||]</div>");
```

But that was absolutely not an succes !! http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/7070/5y1l.png

Any input will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make your selectors more specific like `$('.fc-widget-header.fc-mon')` to only catch the headers.

I got the following code to work:

```
var $calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    viewDisplay: function (view) {
        // Clean up any previously added "dropdowns"
        $('.dropdown').remove();

        // Only add "drowdowns" if the current view is the weekly view
        if (view.name === 'agendaWeek') {

            // Add the "dropdowns" to the day headers
            $('.fc-widget-header.fc-sun, .fc-widget-header.fc-mon, .fc-widget-header.fc-tue, .fc-widget-header.fc-wed, .fc-widget-header.fc-thu, .fc-widget-header.fc-fri, .fc-widget-header.fc-sat')
            .prepend("<div class='dropdown' style='display: inline'>[||] </div>");
        }
    }
});
```

You can check out this jsfiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvakulo/p5f3J/3/

Comment: Regin - Thanks for your code, is there any way to make the div float left ? (http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/2029/yp5r.png)